# How to iterate through raster conversion concurrently while using map function in Python

Tags: arcpy, raster, ascii, for-loop, parallel-processing

I am trying to troubleshoot some issues I'm having with the Python `map` function that is part of a larger problem I'm having with trying to run my code concurrently. Why does `map()` here create an empty output? It runs with no error and creates a map object, but does not create any rasters.

Set-up code:

```
import arcpy
import os
import arcpy

wd = r'myPath'
os.chdir(wd)

def create_raster(input):
    string_out_name = 'EmptyTIFF_' + str(input) + '.tif'
    tif = arcpy.CreateRasterDataset_management(out_path = wd, out_name = string_out_name, pixel_type = '8_BIT_UNSIGNED', number_of_bands = "1")
    string_ascii_name = string_out_name.strip('.tif') + '.asc'
    arcpy.RasterToASCII_conversion(tif, os.path.join(wd, string_ascii_name))    

myList = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

A for loop works and creates ten GeoTIFF and ten ASCII rasters:

```
for i in myList:
    create_raster(i)
```

However, when I try to use map( ), the output is empty. How can I use the map( ) function here?

```
map(create_raster, myList)
```

The reason I'm trying to use map( ) is so that I can use the multiprocessing or threading packages with something like the following (which isn't producing anything):

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    executor.map(create_raster, tif_list)
```

Comment: Is this a GIS question?  It appears to be more of a Python question, and may be better suited to Stack Overflow, than to GIS Stack Exchange.  Eg, if you delete (comment-out) both of the arcpy lines from your `create_raster()` function then add `print(string_out_name + " " + string_ascii_name)` at the end of that function, do you get the same problem?

Comment: You actually actually post the code including the setup section AND the `map()` line to demonstrate how you are actually using the `map()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map()` in Python 3 is evaluated "lazily".  That is, the code of the function that it is calling is not actually run until the result is required.  For more details, see the accepted answer at:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19342331/python-map-calling-a-function-not-working

So to make this work, you can assign the results of the the `map()` to a variable (eg, `result = map(create_raster, myList)`), and then do something with each item in the `result` iterable (eg, assign convert it to a list:
`result_list = list(map(create_raster, myList))`).

So, that would give us:

```
import arcpy
import os
import arcpy

wd = r'myPath'
os.chdir(wd)

def create_raster(input):
    string_out_name = 'EmptyTIFF_' + str(input) + '.tif'
    tif = arcpy.CreateRasterDataset_management(out_path = wd, out_name = string_out_name, pixel_type = '8_BIT_UNSIGNED', number_of_bands = "1")
    string_ascii_name = string_out_name.strip('.tif') + '.asc'
    arcpy.RasterToASCII_conversion(tif, os.path.join(wd, string_ascii_name))    

myList = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

result_list = list(map(create_raster, myList))
```

You're not actually doing anything with `result_list`, but this will force it to actually run the `create_raster()` for each item.

NB:  I can't comment on the concurrency of either the `map()` function or the `list()` function.  But the following may be of use:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67686563/run-same-function-parallelly-with-different-items-in-the-list-in-python